# Java Collision detection moving platform Nan

Tags: java

I've been trying to make a moving platform in my 2D platformer game and when trying to make the player move along with the platform, I wrote this. For some reason, this causes the players X position to be "NaN", and when printing out tdX, it outputs alternating "1.0"s and  "NaN"s

```
//delta X
double dX = newPoint.getX()-oldPoint.getX();
//delta Y
double dY = newPoint.getY()-oldPoint.getY();
//tdX and tdY are supposed to be 1 if their matching variable
// is positive and -1 if it is negative.
double tdX = dX/Math.abs(dX);
double tdY = dY/Math.abs(dY);
System.out.println(tdX);
//If the player is standing on the platform
if(Display.player.me(0,1).intersects(super.phys)) {
    //Add percentSpeed% of deltaX to the players location
    Display.player.loc.setLocation(Display.player.loc.getX()+((dX/100) *
                              (percentSpeed*tdX)),Display.player.loc.getY());
}
```

If I take the *tdX part out of the last line, it works but because then it doesn't push the player in the right direction when going backwards because it isnt being multiplied by -1...
That would mean that tdX was created incorrectly but I dont see how it isnt... Please help me.

Comment: `tdX` will be `NaN` if `dX` is `0`. Same for `tdY` and `dY`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`NaN` is the result of dividing a floating-point zero by a floating-point zero.

A few examples:

```
float f = 0.0f;
double d = 0.0;

// f/f is NaN
// f/d is NaN
// d/f is NaN
// d/d is NaN
```

Dividing an integer zero by an integer zero results with a runtime exception.

Comment: I finally realized that my problem was that
1: I am a complete idiot
2: I had 2 moving objects, one which caused the nan and one which didnt, therefore causing the alternating outputs.
3: One of my moving objects moved only vertically, and therefore had a delta X of 0.

Thank you so much for the help tho

Comment: Ill set you as the correct answer once the timer runs out.

Comment: hrmmmm
I replaced the tdX and tdY setters with
                double tdX = ((dX < 0) ? -1:1);
  double tdY = ((dY < 0) ? -1:1);
But tdX is only ever 1.0?? Why is this?

Comment: @user3697441: If I understand correctly, then your previous problem was with each one of these variables being equal to zero. So I think that you should simply change the `<` to `<=` in each one of the conditions.

Comment: yea the problem was that I kept on forgetting that 0/num is allowed even though num/0 isnt.

Answer (score 0):

If `dX` = `0` (i.e. `newPoint.getX() == oldPoint.getX()`), you compute `0/0`, which results in `tdX` = `NaN`.

Answer (score 0):

`tdX` will be `NaN` if `dX` is `0`, because dividing a `double` by `0` results in `NaN`. Same for `tdY` and `dY`.

You probably want to check specifically for 0:

```
double tdX = dX == 0 ? 0 : dX/Math.abs(dX);
double tdY = dY == 0 ? 0 : dY/Math.abs(dY);
```